# Laravel 5 - get ID by other field properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get the ID of a user in a `middleware` by searching with his email. I thought about doing it like this in one of two ways.

First, creating a function in the model `User`:

```
public function getIdByMail($query, $q) {
    return $query->select('id')->where('email', $q);
}
```

Second, using this function in my middleware

```
use App\User;
...
$user = User::getIdByMail($user_id);
```

And it doesn't work, nor am I even sure it's the right way...

Comment: Try `return $query->select('id')->where('email', $q)->first();` Not sure why you want to do that, do you mean the logged in user?

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping ! You don't think it's better to use the model for that kind of calls to the DB ?

Comment: You're welcome. Can you firstly tell me WHY you're trying to get the user by their email. Personally I'd just do `$user = User::find($user_id)->id;`

Comment: Sorry last comment is supposed to be what Pawel put

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it. No need for extra methods in model. Eloquent makes everything pretty simple.

```
$id = User::where('email', $email)->first()->id;
```

Comment: Alternative:
`$id = User::where('email', $email)->first(['id']);`

Comment: Thanks ! But is it not more "the right way" to interact with the DB only from the model ?

Comment: @JeremyBelolo One can argue about that for sure, but converting this oneliner to a method in a model and then calling it just feels like too much for something so simple. If the query is more complicated or used a lot, then moving it makes sense for sure.

Answer (score 0):

To interact with the DB only from the model than

```
$post= \App\Models\Category::where([
        ['name' , $name]])->first()->id;
```